# Rails AJAX form submit modal errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a bootstrap 4 modal with a form in it and if the form has any validation errors then those errors should be displayed on the modal after the user has clicked submit.

So my form is using remote: true to send the ajax request, its hitting the controller fine, and I am using in my controller the following code:

```
def create
  if @customer.save
    redirect_to customers_path
  else
    if @customer.errors.any?
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

the new.js.erb code is as follows

```
$('.modal-content').html("<%= j render 'customers/new' %>");
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

Now the problem I am having is that the errors are showing up on the modal, but I am now unable to close the modal again without refreshing the page. When I try to close the modal I get the following error in the console *`Uncaught Error: Modal is transitioning`*. If I fill in correct details I am able to submit the form and create the customer, and the modal then closes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, please include the details of the `$(document).ready()` js code? Where is it? Are you using turbolink?

Answer (score 0):

Close the modal only on success. On failure you wouldn't need to open it again like you are with `$('#modal').modal('show');`

For this you will need to respond with JS for both success/failure. And Redirects won't work if you are using `remote: true` on the form.